# AndroidStudio Adding an image to draw with srcCompat

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to do a drawer activity with Android Studio and I'm wanting to personalize the icons used. I've downloaded the icons I want to use and for the most part, it's okay.

In fact, I can modify all the `android:icon` icons but I have no idea how to modify the `app:srcCompat` icons. I don't know how to detect the image I want to use in this case...

Do you know how I can do it? Could you explain this to me?
Thanks a lot!

Edit: The file I'm working on as a base is the generated project with Drawer activity as the main activity. For example, if I wanted to modify the icon in the `nav_header_main.xml` file, how could I do to have my image (.png) transformed in a way detected by Android Studio as compatible with `srcCompat`

Comment: Can you explain us which file are you modifying?

Comment: I've added it now, is it precise enough or is it too vague?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I was blind! I was wondering how I could add my icons but they were, I was just mistaking on the address... `@android:drawable/...` is obviously not `@drawable/...` but I didn't notice. So be aware that there is a difference and it'll be okay I think!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your image file is in res/drawable folder(or drawable-xhdpi/xxhdpi, determined by your design)

Refer it by `app:srcCompact="@drawable/$IMAGE_FILE_NAME"` in your xml.

Then you should see what you want.

Please check [the doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#XmlBitmap) to further understand the official usage.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't even have to do that... In fact I'm a little bit stupid... I'll post the answer